# How does localization default when a language is not present? [EXPLAINED]

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nslocalizedstring

**Update: Solution**

You support English and Spanish.

If the list of languages in the Settings app is Portuguese, Spanish, English then Spanish will be shown to the user. If the list has been Portuguese, English, Spanish then English would be shown to the user.

For further info, check accepted answer.

---

**Original Post**

I'm localizing an app still in development following the [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) by Ray Wenderlich.

So far, everything is going great, but I find the app defaulting to the wrong language when the device configuration is not supported.

For instance, I support English and Spanish. But when running the app with the device set to Portuguese, the localization from <strike>Spanish</strike> the last valid language is loaded.

In general, the idea to check 'CFBundleDevelopmentRegion' seems to be the most common suggestion. Though it's set to "en" the app doesn't seem to care. Tried setting it to en_US as well but with no result.

From the official documentation, when a string key is not found, the key itself should be returned, which would be great as my keys are the English strings. But this doesn't seem to be happening either.

Does anybody know how this is handled or how can I work around it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The displayed language is based on the locales you support and the order of languages chosen by the user in the Settings app.

Run the Settings app and go to General, International, then Language. Start at the top of the language list and go down the list until the language matches one of the languages supported by your app. That is how it works.

You support English and Spanish.

If the list of languages in the Settings app is Portuguese, Spanish, English then Spanish will be shown to the user. If the list has been Portuguese, English, Spanish then English would be shown to the user.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for! A little weird behaviour if you ask me, but at least now I know why it's working the way it does. Thanks again!

Comment: Now that I think about it, it should be possible to force a specific language as default, right?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:**

Sorry i understand wrong the question.

So YES, **when a string key is not found, the key itself should be returned**!
It is absolutely so! If you set your string in english like:

```
NSLocalizedString(@"Hello",@"");
```

and you don't have the `Portuguese` file, will be returned `Hello`.

**ORIGINAL POST:**

The **language of the default development region** imposted in your `Info.plist` file for the target.

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's what I've seeing everywhere. The 'CFBundleDevelopmentRegion' is that exact same configuration. Doesn't matter if I set it to en or en_US (choosing "United States"), it won't change the behaviour.

Comment: Hi Mateo, thanks again for your reply. You are absolutely, this is the expected behaviour as detailed by Apple documentation. However, somehow I managed to avoid it. If the language file for the device configuration is missing, the keys are not loaded, and some other language file is used instead.

Comment: @maddy had the right answer! It has to do with the languages order in the settings page.